# Ajax Radio button not set (Edit mode )

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
  var sGender = value.UsrMasGender;  //(Return  Value )
    if(sGender==="Male"){  //Set  ti  variable 
         $('#rdGender').find(':radio[name=rdGender][value="Male"]').prop('checked', true);  // #rdGender is  name  of the  RB
         $('#rdGender').find(':radio[name=rdGender][value="Fe-Male"]').prop('checked', false);
    }else{
         $('#rdGender').find(':radio[name=rdGender][value="Fe-Male"]').prop('checked', true); 
         $('#rdGender').find(':radio[name=rdGender][value="Male"]').prop('checked', false);
          alert("Gender : "+sGender);)
                            }
```

//Values Returning ,But buttons not set according to  the functions

```
<div class = "form-group"> 
    <label for = "UserMas" class = "col-sm-2 control-label">Gender</label> 
    <div class = "col-sm-10"> 
        <input type="radio" name="rdGender" id="Male" value="Male" > Male 
        <input type="radio" name="rdGender" id="FeMale" value="Fe-Male"> Fe-male 
    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide your HTML?

Comment: <div class = "form-group">
                <label for = "UserMas" class = "col-sm-2 control-label">Gender</label>
                <div class = "col-sm-10">
                    <input type="radio" name="rdGender" id="Male" value="Male" >
                Male
                    <input type="radio" name="rdGender" id="FeMale" value="Fe-Male">
                Fe-male</td>
                </div>
            </div>

Comment: you don't have id `rdGender` anywhere.

Comment: So where is the element with `id="rdGender"`?

Comment: I am  using  name="rdGender"

Comment: It is not required but your jQuery code `$("#rdGender")` is selecting an element that does not exist in the DOM. It only makes sense to use elements that DO exist.

Answer (score 0):

Try attr instead of prop. `i.e btn.attr("checked", true);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("input[name=rdGender][value=Male]").prop('checked', true);

OR

$("input[name=rdGender][value=FeMale]").prop('checked', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: use class `form-group` to find your radio buttons.

```js
var sGender = "Male";  //(Return  Value )
if(sGender==="Male"){
     $('.form-group').find(':radio[name=rdGender][value="Male"]').prop('checked', true);  // #rdGender is  name  of the  RB
     $('.form-group').find(':radio[name=rdGender][value="Fe-Male"]').prop('checked', false);
}else{
     $('.form-group').find(':radio[name=rdGender][value="Fe-Male"]').prop('checked', true); 
     $('.form-group').find(':radio[name=rdGender][value="Male"]').prop('checked', false);

                        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "form-group"> <label for = "UserMas" class = "col-sm-2 control-label">Gender</label> <div class = "col-sm-10"> <input type="radio" name="rdGender" id="Male" value="Male" > Male <input type="radio" name="rdGender" id="FeMale" value="Fe-Male"> Fe-male</td> </div> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code selects the radio buttons, then filters to leave the one with a matching value, then sets `checked` property to `true`:

```
$(':radio[name="rdGender"]').filter(function() {
    return this.value == sGender;
})
.prop( 'checked', true );
```

Or, assuming your ids are unique:

```
$('#Male').prop( 'checked', sGender == 'Male' );
$('#FeMale').prop( 'checked', sGender == 'Fe-Male' );
```

Comment: Thankx..appriciating  it  is  working..thankx  again

Comment: Glad I could be of help. Feel free to upvote and accept this answer if your found it helpful.